# Can I change/modify URL's once my device is whiltelisted with Google?

Tags: chromecast

I'm planning to develop a app using Chromecast. To whitelist my device I have to provide atleast one valid URL to Google. My question here is can I change or modify the registered URL's in future? Will it break my app if I change URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the same place that you provided your original URL to change the URL's.